# JavaScript: get webpart context by DOM ID

Tags: web-part, javascript, client-object-model

I have an already loaded page with webparts.

I want to get the webpart context object by using IDs which I can get from the DOM, e.g. webpartid="bf385785-6507-4af1-b419-b8bf30dc5103"

Basically the same context object I get when I hook into the client side rendering with:

```
OnPostRender = function( ctx ) {
   // do sg
}
```

Anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand what you want, but I think you are looking for the `g_ctxDict` object. It holds all the "ctx" objects for all your list webparts on the page.

[image]

```
for(var prop in g_ctxDict) { 
   console.log(g_ctxDict[prop].listName) 
}
```